# A replacement for the anti pattern ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, jboss

During a job meeting.I have heard that Thread Local is absolutely an anti pattern because new Application servers uses new Thread technologies called new IO.In fact,they told me that the problem with ThreadLocal is that a complete thread must wait for the database query to return a response and that's absolutely a waste of resources(memory as well as CPU).
New developed Thread strategy uses a pool of threads so when a thread is not needed any more it will return to pool.What i have heard is that this new Technology is implemented in new AS such us Jboss,Websphere...(i'm not sure).
Can i use it locally with Apache tomcat for example?(if it's possible documentation on that fact)

Comment: You must have badly misunderstood something they said: what does `ThreadLocal` have to do with Java's NIO package, and how does it make it an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ThreadLocal` is a side character in your story. What you have heard about is *asynchronous request processing*, which is helped, among other things, by the NIO library.

In this programming paradigm, you don't get a simple method like

```
Response processRequest(Request req)
```

Instead you get

```
void requestReceived(Request req, Response resp)
```

and within this method you will usually just start the processing by preparing the back-end request and calling its method which will look like

```
execute(Query q, ResultCallback cb)
```

and the framework will call your `ResultCallback`'s method `resultReady(Result res)` which will contain the query result.

The main point here is that the method `requestReceived` will return *immediately*, and will not occupy the thread while the back-end request is being processed at the back-end subsystem.

BTW another name for this style of programming is *continuation-passing style* or CPS. It is because when you call a function, you don't wait for its return value, but rather pass a callback into it which will be called with the function's result, and which implements the *continuation* of the total request processing.

#### How ThreadLocal fits into this

If you have followed what I have said above, it should already be clear to you that in this style of request processing, `ThreadLocal`s are a useless concept because the request processing freely jumps from thread to thread, and in a way which is completely outside of your control.

Comment: Just to point out, ThreadLocal is not a useless concept :) You just need to make sure, that you clean out whatever ThreadLocals you created before you gave away control of your thread. For example, ThreadLocals used in Spring transaction management.

Comment: @Yuriy They may not be theoretically unusable, but they are inconvenient to the point of being useless in practice. It is much more natural to attach request-scoped objects to the object provided by the framework, which travels along during the processing of the request.

Answer (score 1):

ThreadLocal has basically nothing to do with databases or ThreadPools/ExecutorServices. ThreadLocal just means that the value stored in it is just visible to the Thread how set it. This doesn't cause any blocking. You must confuse some things there.

- ThreadLocal: Stores variable per Thread.
- "new IO": They most likely meant the [java.nio package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html). It about reading/writing data without blocking.
- Threadpools/Executorservice: Bunch of Threads where you can submit Runnables to. You can use [ExecutorServices](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) in any Java application, because they are part of the standard library.
- For accessing the database you normally use a dedicated system like [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/), which manages Threads and database connections

Answer (score 0):

I think that i misunderstand the subject.
Well,i will explain in detail what i have heard.
When using ThreadLocal.If we have for example a query to DataBase or JMS call .The thread must be alive for the response to return (suppose that takes 15 minute for example).The thread will be in a waiting situation waiting for Db to return response.so it's a waste for CPU as well as memory.
New Thread management technology uses a pool of threads.In fact during the waiting time.The thread will be used to server another client.
That's what i have heard.
To Marko Topolnik:What you have exposed is asynchronous calls and it does nothing to do with Threads.

Comment: You seem to be very confused indeed. The only way to achieve what you are describing, that the thread can be used to process other requests instead of waiting, is by using the asynchronous programming techniques which I describe.

Comment: The only other, remotely related, technique are *green threads*, which are definitely *not* what is used in Java.

Comment: Marko please explain to me:Did you mean that the thread after sending an asychron call will be used in another request?

Comment: Marko please explain to me:Did you mean that the thread after sending an asychron call will be used in another request?

Comment: Of course, that's the whole point of asynchronous programming, just as you have described it. The method `processRequest` in my example returns immediately, which means that the thread on which it was called is free to go about any other business. And as long as the database request is being processed, **no threads at all** are being occupied.

Comment: @Marko: "no threads at all" is an exaggeration. Some thread has to wait reply from database and initiate callback execution. Even if asynchronous database drivers are used (which a rare and poorly debugged), they have to use a selector thread or other kind of background IO threads.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Yes, you are right. My emphasis was on asymptotic behavior: 100 concurrent requests will still occupy just 1 thread waiting for the database (assuming asynchronous database IO, of course).

Answer (score 0):

ThreadLocals, thread pools, and new IO can cooperate quite well. All you need is to define thread factory when creating a threadpool so that each new thread would get correct threadlocal value at the moment of creation. This value, for example, can keep a reference to java.nio.channels.Selector singleton. Another thread local variable can hold reference to the thread pool itself, so submitting new tasks to the thread pool can be simplified.

Asynchronous framework https://github.com/rfqu/df4j uses thread locals intensively this way.